# How can I use sys_sendto() under kernel mode?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I'm writing a DDoS firewall by netfilter, I want to send a socket packet to another computer under kernel mode. But the compiler warned me that the symbol "sys_sendto" was undefined. So how can I use these sys_socketcalls in my module? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the `sys_sendto` system call, you might be able to use the `sock_sendmsg` function, which is how [`sys_sendto` is implemented](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.1/net/socket.c#L1673).